# Equality test function

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, vector

Below is a function which aims to perform an equality test between adjacent numbers in a one dimensional vector.

This 1D vector will have values which will represent an nxn grid. [ v is the vector]

When they are equal it returns false.

For example consider this 3x3 grid:

```
i\j| 0 | 1 | 2
0  | 1 | 2 | 3
1  | 4 | 5 | 6
2  | 7 | 8 | 9
```

The issue with the code I wrote is that not all of the numbers in the grid will have 4 other adjacent numbers and testing for indexes which don't exist e.g when trying to compare the number above the top left number in the grid (1 in the example) might lead to some inaccurate outcomes.

In addition to this what I wrote seems not to be the most efficient way to go about it. Surely there could be a simpler way to do this than having to list 5 new variables?

```
for( int i= 0; i < n ; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        int x = v[convert(i, j, n)];
        int c = v[convert(i-1, j, n)];
        int s = v[convert(i+1, j, n)];
        int b = v[convert(i, j+1, n)];
        int n = v[convert(i, j-1, n)];

        if (x == c || x == s || x == b || x == n ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

//another function used to convert 2d into 1D index
 int convert(int row, int col, int rowlen){
    return row*rowlen+col;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In general case, an alternative to avoid bound checks is to surround the array by "sentinel" (transforming your 3x3 array in 5x5 array), and work normally with the "center" of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an efficient way to do this, you should consider the cache locality of your values, how much index conversion you do, how many bounds tests you do, and how many comparisons are needed.

First thing to note is that you do not need to compare to the left and above when you're already comparing to the right and below.  This is because the left/up test will happen when testing to the right/down on the next iteration.  So immediately, that halves the amount of testing.

A first optimization would be to split the operation into row tests and column tests:

```
// Test adjacency in rows
for (const int *rowptr = v, *end = v + n * n;
     rowptr != end;
     rowptr += n)
{
    for (int col = 1; col < n; col++) {
        if (rowptr[col-1] == rowptr[col]) return false;
    }
}

// Test adjacency in columns
for (const int *row0ptr = v, *row1ptr = v + n, *end = v + n * n;
     row1ptr != end;
     row0ptr = row1ptr, row1ptr += n)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
        if (row0ptr[col] == row1ptr[col]) return false;
    }
}
```

To avoid making two passes through the entire array, you'd need to combine these, but it starts getting a bit messy.  Notice how the two separate passes currently have different bounds (the row-tests loop from column 1 to n, whereas the column tests loop from row 0 to n-1).

Combining the loops would only make sense if `n` is quite large and if it's absolutely critical that this piece of code is fast.  The idea is to perform a single pass through the entire array, avoiding any issues with stuff like L1 cache misses on the second pass.

It would look something like this:

```
const int *row0ptr = v, *row1ptr = v + n, *end = v + n * n
for ( ; row1ptr != end; row0ptr = row1ptr, row1ptr += n)
{
    // Test first column
    if (row0ptr[0] == row1ptr[0]) return false;

    // Test row0 and remaining columns
    for (int col = 1; col < n; col++) {
        if (row0ptr[col-1] == row0ptr[col]) return false;
        if (row0ptr[col] == row1ptr[col]) return false;
    }
}

// Test last row
for (int col = 1; col < n; col++) {
    if (row0ptr[col-1] == row0ptr[col]) return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Apologies, I am new to c++, I am not familiar with the style of code here( once again apologies). How is it that  testing for left would also allow us to test for right and vice versa for up and down? Would you by any chance be able to explain the code for the first for loop? many thanks.

Comment: Okay, consider left and right pairs at position `x`: (x-1, x) and (x, x+1).  If x is 0, you would only test on the right due to array bounds, so you test (0,1).  On the next iteration, x is 1.  If you test on the left, you're testing (0,1), which was already tested on the previous iteration as being on the right.  So it's redundant.  The same goes for columns.

Comment: I see what you mean here. Thing is you would need to check each single number with all its adjacent numbers in the grid. The method described above would not check the adjacent numbers for every single number in the grid.

Comment: Yes it does.  Think about it.

Comment: Just went over it in my head. Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd recommend breaking up the logic because it's getting quite convoluted. But something like this works, it avoids going outside the grid by adding extra checks on `i` and `j` and it may avoid unnecessary calls to `convert` since if one of the earlier tests is true the later tests aren't performed.

```
     int x = v[convert(i, j, n)];
     if (i > 0 && x == v[convert(i-1, j, n)])
         return false;
     if (i < n - 1 && x == v[convert(i+1, j, n)])
         return false;
     if (j > 0 && x == v[convert(i, j-1, n)])
         return false;
     if (j < n - 1 && x == v[convert(i, j+1, n)])
         return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. This is helpful in solving the issue with non existing indexes in the grid. Is there any other methods which would be able to solve this more efficiently considering this has 2 for loops and 4 if statements?

Comment: @James I'm sure you could tweak it a little, but its the nature of the problem isn't it? You need to loop through the grid and you need to make four tests at every coordinate.

Comment: @James Four `if`s or one `if` and four conditions... There's probably no difference. Go with whatever is easier to read. Note that this layout is protecting the code from a whole bunch of cases that were't even considered in the question and a eliminates lot of extra work if the function exits early. It's a win on many levels.

Comment: @user4581301 what kind of cases do you mean for example?

Comment: As I point out in my answer, you do not need to test on all four sides.

Comment: @James For example the `i > 0` prevents `convert(0-1, j, n)`-> `convert(-1, j, n)` -> `-1*rowlen+col` whiich will almost certainly result in a negative number being used as an index for `v` and the grand kabong of [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) from reaching outside the bounds of `v`. Fast code is useless when it can give the wrong answer.